# Checking the url is up or not?

Tags: java, url

I need to check whether a particular url is up or not.
The format of the url is like

```
http://IP:port
```

When I use `java.net.URL` class then I get `java.net.SocketException` or `java.net.ConnectException`.

When i ping these IPs, I find them up then why java is not able to recognise them?

The code I'm writing is

```
URL url = new URL( urlString );
HttpURLConnection httpConn =  (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
httpConn.setRequestMethod( "HEAD" ); 
httpConn.connect();
```

Port number is must to use!
How can I check them using java?

Comment: you do realize that the ConnectException signals that, from the perspective of the machine this code is running on, the URL is "not up", right? If the definition of "not up" is "cannot be connected to from this machine".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works just fine from here:

```
URL url = new URL( "http://google.com/" );
HttpURLConnection httpConn =  (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
httpConn.setRequestMethod( "HEAD" ); 
httpConn.connect();

System.out.println( "google.com : " + httpConn.getResponseCode());
```

or for failure:

```
URL url = new URL( "http://google.com:666/" );
HttpURLConnection httpConn =  (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
httpConn.setRequestMethod( "HEAD" ); 
try{
    httpConn.connect();
     System.out.println( "google.com : " + httpConn.getResponseCode());
}catch(java.net.ConnectException e){
     System.out.println( "google.com:666 is down ");
}
```

Comment: Yes. But I've to do it the port number!

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the servers are up and running (responding to ping), but that no HTTP server is listening on that port.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is something else going on but I found this page to have it doing exactly what you want:
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0059.html

They don't have port numbers in the url though.

Comment: Could you share the ip:port or is it internal? Can you find an example that we can test?